Is there any way to modify strings inside .pcap files with python scapy wthiout yielding an error?
I am experimenting with scapy in python and captured a test pcap which only contains a transfer of a file over HTTP. The contents of the file are plaintext.
I am trying to basically change the Server string:
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.11.8

to a different one, let's say:
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: A custom one

The thing is that after this change, the size of the packet changes and as a result a lot of TCP packets are marked as retransmissions, the content of the HTTP packet says that bytes are missing etc.
Is there a way to modify strings - and the corresponding size fields - so that the pcap remains without errors?
P.S. I tried changing the Frame Length and Capture Length fields of Ether layer but still was getting errors.
My demo script for the time being is:
from scapy.all import *

def replace_user_agent(packets):
    i = 0
    for packet in packets:
        i+=1
        if packet.haslayer(Raw):
            raw = packet[Raw].load
            if b"SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.11.8" in raw:
                raw = raw.replace(b"SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.11.8", b"A custom one"+ b" " * (len("SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.11.8") - len("A custom one"))) # cover the missing length with spaces
                packet[Raw].load = raw

                # Recalculate length fields and checksums
                if packet.haslayer(IP):
                    del packet[IP].len  # Recalculate IP length
                    del packet[IP].chksum  # Recalculate IP checksum
                if packet.haslayer(TCP):
                    del packet[TCP].chksum  # Recalculate TCP checksum
                elif packet.haslayer(UDP):
                    del packet[UDP].len  # Recalculate UDP length
                    del packet[UDP].chksum  # Recalculate UDP checksum


    return packets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_pcap = "input.pcap"
    output_pcap = "output.pcap"

    packets = rdpcap(input_pcap)
    modified_packets = replace_user_agent(packets)
    wrpcap(output_pcap, modified_packets)

This script does and does not do what I am trying to achieve. It basically replaces the Server string with my shorter custom one, and for the missing bytes it just uses spaces.

If you make changes to one TCP packet which change the size of the payload you would need to adjust sequence numbers and acks of every following packet in the same TCP connection.

@Steffen Ullrich and what would be the corresponding fields that I should look into and possibly change for that purpose? (from wireshark for example)

TCP header - sequence and acknowledgment numbers. And of course you need to adjust all checksum if you make changes.

Sounds to me that what you need is a capture at a higher layer. If your application uses HTTP you might want to use HAR files instead of pcap. HAR is a JSON format that captures the actual HTTP session and will be much easier to modify and replay.
It will also abstract away lower layers (SSL, HTTP/2) which would make modification very difficult.

@bd55 did you had a chance to take a look at the answer? Thanks!

Adding Padding as needed to the modified packet removes the warning/errors. pcap file contains the curl request to this minimal web server.
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.utils import rdpcap
from scapy.layers.inet import TCP
from scapy.layers.http import *

def parse_pkts(pkts, write=True):
    for pkt in pkts:
        if Raw in pkt and pkt[Ether][TCP].sport == 8000 and 'Server: ' in pkt[Raw].fields['load'].decode('ascii'):
            #print(pkt.show())
            needle = "netcat.local"
            new_needle= 'XXXX'
            payload = pkt[Raw].fields['load'].decode('ascii').replace(needle, "XXXX")
            print(pkt[Raw].fields['load'], len(pkt))
            pkt[Raw].load = payload.encode('ascii') #fields['load']
            
            if write:
                pad = "\x00"*(len(needle) - len(new_needle))
                pkt = pkt/Padding(pad)

            print(pkt[Raw].fields['load'], len(pkt))
        if write:
            wrpcap(f'{dstdir}/test-scapy-mangled.pcap', pkt, append=True)
    
dstdir = '/home/lmc/projects/forensics'
pkts=rdpcap(f"{dstdir}/test-netcat-local.pcapng")

parse_pkts(pkts)

print("\n")
pkts=rdpcap(f'{dstdir}/test-scapy-mangled.pcap')
parse_pkts(pkts, write=False)

Output
b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: netcat.local\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n\nresponse from parent.example.com:8000\n' 165
b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: XXXX\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n\nresponse from parent.example.com:8000\n' 165



b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: XXXX\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n\nresponse from parent.example.com:8000\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' 165
b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: XXXX\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n\nresponse from parent.example.com:8000\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' 165

tshark does not complain
tshark -r /home/lmc/projects/forensics/test-scapy-mangled.pcap
    1   0.000000    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 74 36994 → 8000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65495 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM TSval=3035651634 TSecr=0 WS=128
    2   0.000017    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 74 8000 → 36994 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65483 Len=0 MSS=65495 SACK_PERM TSval=3035651634 TSecr=3035651634 WS=128
    3   0.000027    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 66 36994 → 8000 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=3035651634 TSecr=3035651634
    4   0.000068    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    HTTP 143 GET / HTTP/1.1 
    5   0.000074    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 66 8000 → 36994 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=78 Win=65408 Len=0 TSval=3035651634 TSecr=3035651634
    6   0.000086    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 165 HTTP/1.1 200 OK  [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
    7   0.000094    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 66 36994 → 8000 [ACK] Seq=78 Ack=100 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=3035651634 TSecr=3035651634
    8   0.000104    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    HTTP 66 HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
    9   0.000133    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 66 36994 → 8000 [FIN, ACK] Seq=78 Ack=101 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=3035651634 TSecr=3035651634
   10   0.000140    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 66 8000 → 36994 [ACK] Seq=101 Ack=79 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=3035651634 TSecr=3035651634

tshark shows a warning if there's no padding
HTTP 165 HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Packet size limited during capture]
Warning
If the new string is longer than the original then the payload will be silently truncated by scapy
            needle     = "netcat.local"
            new_needle = 'XXXX.YYYYYYY.ZZZ'
            payload = pkt[Raw].fields['load'].decode('ascii').replace(needle, new_needle)

Payload truncated to
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: XXXX.YYYYYYY.ZZZ\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n\nresponse from parent.example.com:8
